# Facebook login using phonegap (cordova 1.6.0) not working for Android

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

Trying with cardova 1.6.0 , getting alerts

1. Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login!
2. Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on auth.status!

pls help

I'am referring this link 
http://marguspala.com/add-facebook-login-to-phonegap-android-app-easiest-way/

Answer (score 1):

just follow the instruction on github, it work all fine with me, I'm using cordova 1.7.0 and Xcode 4.1

Answer (score 1):

ya just follow the instruction on github, it works fine with with me also on Cordova 1.7 and xcode 4.2. you may have to change if statement of  "FB.login if (response.session)"  to "if (response.authResponse)" .

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and had to downgrade to cordova 1.5.0 to make it work. Haven't tried with 1.7 but since the fb plugin hasn't been developed for a while I doubt it will work. 1.5.0 is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Commit ID 1c8f97f982b69af992c5b0ab336969f4bf02a53d of https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect worked for me in Cordova 1.7 / Xcode 4.3.2.

However, it's a bit tricky, so if you're new to ios development, it's gonna take some trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you have not used deviceready in the code.

so kindly use the following code.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    try {
    alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
        FB.init({
            appId : "256439131120685",
            nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
            useCachedDialogs : false
        });

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}, false);
```

It is working fine for me.

Have you signed your application and entered the Hash key in your FB application on https://developers.facebook.com/apps under Native Android App and Configured for Android SSO should be disabled.